# "Сценическая река"?

Tags: лексическая-сочетаемость, лексическая

"Река Алатна — одна из шести диких и сценических рек, частично протекающих в пределах границ арктического Национального парка Gates, что на Аляске."
Это перевод с английского. В словосочетании "сценическая река" слово "сценическая" явно неуместно, безграмотно. Каким словом его нужно заменить, чтобы 
передать (предположительно) смысл английского первоисточника и сделать словосочетание грамотным?
Английского первоисточника у меня нет.

Comment: Что-то мне кажется, что проще спросить на ell.SE что имеется в_виду под scenic и wild из ответов ниже, и уже реконструировать это значение в русском (а он богатый), раз уж мы так заботимся о точности перевода :) Похоже, я так и сделаю.

Comment: Так что, ждать Ваш ответ, Alexey Burdin, или не ждать? Если не ждать, то буду закрывать вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо всем за ответы!

Comment: Очень существенные уточнения, Alexey Burdin. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По-видимому в оригинале было слово scenic - "сценический; театральный; живописный; сценичный; видовой; жанровый; наигранный; напыщенный; декоративный". И больше всего здесь подходит слово живописный.

А вот, похоже и [первоисточник](http://www.amusingplanet.com/2013/03/the-meandering-alatna-river-in-alaska.html):

> The Alatna River is one of the six federally designated wild and scenic river partially contained within the boundaries of Gates of the Arctic National Park, Alaska. It is called one of the most beautiful rivers in the United States.

Похоже что wild здесь все-таки не бурный а скорее "девственный" (как "девственная природа"). [National Wild and Scenic Rivers System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Wild_and_Scenic_Rivers_System) это официальный статус для охраны заповедных рек от хозяйственного влияния.

Comment: Словосочетания "девственный лес", "девственный уголок природы" являются общепринятыми; а вот словосочетания "девственная река"   в русском языке нет. Хотя по смыслу оно бы, скорее всего, подошло.

Comment: @МатвейДёмин, попробуйте подобрать из [переводов слова primitive](https://slovari.yandex.ru/primitive/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4/), у меня не получилось.

Comment: Мультитран предлагает перевести "wild river" как "заповедная река". О, тут все сразу есть: "scenic and wild rivers" = "живописные и заповедные реки", "Wild and Scenic Rivers Act" = "Закон о заповедных реках".

Comment: Спасибо, Artemix!

Answer (score 3):

[Вот что мне ответили на ell.SE:](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/58443/19187)
Похоже, wild и scenic это термины для классификации рек для US конгресса. http://www.rivers.gov/wsr-act.php
Я попробую перевести именно про wild и scenic оттуда.

> Wild реки или части рек, которые свободны от запруженностей и обычно недоступные, кроме чем по тропинкам; с водяными бассейнами и береговыми линиями естественно-природными и незагрязнённой водой. Такие реки представляют остатки первозданной Америки.
>   Scenic реки -- такие реки или части рек, которые свободны от запруженностей, с береговыми линиями и водяными бассейнами и всё ещё довольно первозданными, но доступными посредством дорог.

То есть, действительно, как отражено в [другом ответе](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/58440/19187), wild это совсем дикая, нетронутая природа, а scenic это то, чем можно полюбоваться и для туристов сделаны маршруты и точки, откуда смотреть.

Я даже не знаю, как такое перевести одним словом. :)

Comment: Адаптированные, благоустроенные, освоенные, подготовленные (для туристов).

Answer (score 2):

Плохие переводчики любят заменять английские слова на русские с похожими корнями, поэтому вероятно, что в оригинале было scenic (из возможных значений слова в данном контексте подошло бы "живописный" или "красивый"). "Дикий" (очевидно, wild) могло иметь смысл необжитости, малонаселённости тех мест.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы перевел как "заповедных и туристических рек". Если необходима особая точность, то в скобочках добавил примечание переводчика, хотя особой неободимости в нем не вижу.

Answer (score 0):

В источнике было явно scenic - живописная.
Определение "дикая" тоже как-то не очень. Может быть, "бурная"? Но это требует дополнительной проверки. А может, имеется ввиду "протекающая по дикой природе".